# How to write JUnit test case for the below class?

Tags: java, junit

As i am a junit beginner please help in writing test case for the below class

My program is as follows:

```
 public class One
    {
    public void caseOne()   
    {
        int max=0, 
        cardNo=0;
        System.out.println("Name:");
                    String name=br.readLine();
                    System.out.println("Amount:");

                  int amount=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                   int max=0;
                    for(Customer c :custList)
                    {
                        if(c.getCardNo()>max)
                        {
                            max=c.cardNo;
                        }

                    }
                    System.out.println("Your card no:"+(max+1));
                    Customer newCust=new Customer(name,amount,max+1);
                    custList.add(newCust);
    }
}
```

Comment: First test is to see if code compiles

Comment: I don't this compiles.@sindu...can you go through for better code format.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 3):

Unit tests don't test the code, it test the **implementation against the specification** . You did not include what is your code supposed to do. And saying "*well look at the code*" doesn't make sense, because that's already assuming it follows the specification and therefore the unit testing is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In general, methods with `void` return types are difficult to test.

Right now your class has one method with 3-4 responsibilities:

1. parsing input
2. creating customers
3. managing the customer list
4. (?) logging output

Consider turning the above into their own classes, if their responsibility is critical to the application.

For example, maybe your parser only turns files into `List<Map<String, String>>` or `List<Customer>`, and you have a `CustomerRepository` whose job is only to manage to collection of `Customer` objects.

Comment: Or divide them in testable methods

Comment: 4 classes for the code above is *slightly* an overkill

Comment: @UmNyobe The above doesn't compile, and we must assume there is more somewhere. There is always a judgment call to make with introducing classes, but in my experience more problems are caused by having too few classes than too many.